# Contact 7 Form Layout

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Team of legends. I need you help. I need this form like

Col 1
Row 1: Name
Row 2: Email
Row 3 Phone

Col 2
Row Span:  Message

```
<div class="wpcf7-wrap">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  [text* your-name placeholder "Name:"]
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
   [email* your-email placeholder "Emai:"]
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
 [tel* tel-708 placeholder "Phone:"]
</div>

 <div class="col-xs-6">
    [textarea your-message placeholder "Message:"]
 </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 wpcf7-button-wrap">
  [submit "Contact Us"]
</div>
```

Comment: So... what exactly are you trying to do? Your opening `<div>` isn't closed, if that might be the issue...

Comment: It is, not all the code copied through. Sorry, my bad

Comment: There was an image i added on here, but doesn't seem to have uploaded.

Two Columns. 
On the left hand side, three rows (name, email, phone)
On the Right Hands side, a text box that spans the three rows.

Comment: Ah, I think see.... okay I'll take a stab at an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to something like this would be to either use CSS Grid or Flexbox. For this specific question, Flexbox will work, so I'll use that.

Flexbox can equalize the heights of its children, so the key would be to use two columns, where the left is also a Flexbox and contains the three rows. You didn't mention where you want the Submit button, so I left it outside:

```
<div class="wpcf7-wrap">

    <div class="left-column">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            [text* your-name placeholder "Name:"]
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            [email* your-email placeholder "Emai:"]
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            [tel* tel-708 placeholder "Phone:"]
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="right-column">

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            [textarea your-message placeholder "Message:"]
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 wpcf7-button-wrap">
    [submit "Contact Us"]
</div>
```

From there you can create the columns with Flexbox:

```
.wpcf7-wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.left-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.left-column > * {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started at least!

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pz80gx3y/)